# how to make same extrude to other side in object

Tags: extrude

How to make same extrude cut to I did in another side of the same object?

Like this pic here:

[image]

Comment: Please make a proper screenshot and add it as internal image.

Comment: You can try using the mirror modifier.

Comment: @LukeD hi Luke , thanks for answering .. I just want to knew how to make the same shape to the other side ?

Comment: @Akados it doesnt work very well by using mirror

Comment: What's not working very well? Maybe you need to set Object Origin to the center of the mesh and delete half of it? It's really hard to tell just from this picture.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways, tTsure that your object is symmetrical and it's origin is at the center. In the modifier options, choose which axis (x,y, or z) you would like the other extrusion to be.
[image]

Hope this helps